# Backbone updateOnEnter creates new line

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

After pressing [edit] (after a word/definition has been committed) I want to my updateOnEnter method to save the changes to the definition field and lose focus and the field to become uneditable.  Instead, when I press Enter, the cursor jumps to the line below and the field increases in size.

Here is the CodePen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxBZBe

```
var EntryView = Backbone.View.extend({
            model: new Entry(),
            tagName:'div',

            events:{
                'click .edit': 'edit',
                'click .delete': 'delete',
                'keypress .definition': 'updateOnEnter'
            },

            delete: function(ev){
                ev.preventDefault;
                dictionary.remove(this.model);
            },

            edit: function(ev){
                ev.preventDefault;
                this.$('.definition').attr('contenteditable', true).focus();
                // this.$el.addClass('editing');
            },
            close: function(){
                var definition = this.$('.definition').text();
                this.$('.definition').removeattr('contenteditable');
                this.model.set('definition', definition);

            },

            updateOnEnter: function(ev){
                if(ev.which == 13){
                    this.close();
                }
            },

            initialize: function(){
                this.template = _.template($("#dictionary_template").html());

            },

            render: function(){
                this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
                return this;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your close method has an typo. As soon as that line is evaluated it throws an error and stops executing the rest of the code.

```
this.$('.definition').removeattr('contenteditable');
```

Needs to be

```
this.$('.definition').removeAttr('contenteditable'); // Capital A in removeAttr.
```